# OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm developing a project with opencv 2.3 in c++ style.

In the application I load a video and process every frame and do some stuff with the Mat object. After some time I get a Insufficient memory Error.

I capture the frame like:

```
FCapture >> FImage; 
FDetector->execute(FImage);
```

In the execute I copy the image and save it in a std::Vector list. And also check the imageblobs like:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours; 
findContours(FImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

I know its a bit difficult to answer where the problem could be, but it's impossible to post here to whole program code. Maybe someone could tell me where I have to be careful to copy Mat objects or other OpenCv object that could be the reason of the error.

Comment: Sounds like a typical memory leak. Are you freeing the allocated images after use?

Comment: Use `valgrind` on a small test input and see if there are any flagrant errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting:

> In the execute I copy the image and save it in a std::Vector list

and this statement as well:

> After some time I get a Insufficient memory Error.

OpenCV images can be quite big depending on their size, and based on what you said, I think that **your vector is growing faster then you can remove data from it**, causing the insufficient memory error.

Makes sense right? If you keep adding data to the vector, one day you'll run out of memory to store new data.